# Can you turn off Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link on a page by page basis

Tags: visual-studio-2012, signalr, browser-link

I like the inspector feature of Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link.  However, I have a small number of pages, mostly custom audio/video Media Players, which cause the browser to make an exorbitant amount of signalr requests per second... in the range of 200 per second.  So, I would like to disable the feature on those particular pages.

I know it can be disabled accross the entire application or a section of the application by putting the following key in the web.config file.

```
 <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="true" />
```

Is there a way to disable it on a single page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put all of your Media Players in one folder.  Add a custom web.config for the folder.  Add the key to the web.config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```